# Postman: Cannot Create Document with Azure MongoDB API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

When creating the document with [Azure Cosmos DB: MongoDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction), I am facing the below issues which varies on parameters.

When creating collection `UserProfile`, I've created it with Partition Key `username`.

**Request1:** - Without Partition Key

Headers:

```
x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert: true
```

Body:

```
{"username": "test"}
```

Issue:

> The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer
>   components than defined in the the collection.

**Request2:** - With Partition Key

Headers:

```
x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert: true
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: ["username"]
```

Body:

```
{"username": "test"}
```

Issue:

> One of the specified inputs is invalid

**Request3:** - With Partition Key & id specified in body

Headers:

```
x-ms-documentdb-is-upsert: true
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: ["username"]
```

Body:

```
{"id": "test", "username": "test"}
```

Issue:

> PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified
>   in the header

**In any case,**

I am not able to create the document. What are the necessary parameters to create the document which has partition specified?

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. If you're using the Mongo API, you should not use the REST API. While it's technically possible, it is not supported to use both together. 100% do not recommend.
2. partition key needs to be the partition key value, not the path itself, so it would be "test", not "username". It already knows that "username" is the path.